# Make the number $100$ out of digits $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, without repeats

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

How can we make the number $100$, using only the following digits: $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$. You cannot repeat any of them.

Comment: Do you know that there is a solution at all?

Comment: Yes there is forsure an answer

Comment: $((1+4)\times2)^3$ gives $1000$, if that helps.

Comment: $(1+23)\times4$ gives $96$… so close. (Am I allowed to write $23$?)

Comment: Yes U can make any numbers and U can use any sign (ex. 31-4+2=29)

Comment: $3^4 + 21 = 102$ is as close as you're going to get, I think, unless you allow factorials or square roots or some other operation.

Answer (score 22):

Using only basic arithmetic:

> $$ \frac{4\times 3}{.12} =100 $$

Answer (score 18):

How about: $1^3 \cdot 4 = 100_2$

Comment: I don't think it's valid. $100_{10} \neq 100_2$ But idea with other systems is nice. However I didn't find any way to use them.

Comment: I think writing base 2 on L.H.S. would be better

Comment: @saikirangrandhi Och, yea. But have you any idea how?

Answer (score 13):

And solutions with [logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) (here [natural logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm)) and [ceil function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

$$\left\lceil \ln 2^{143}\right\rceil = 100
= \sqrt{\left\lceil \ln 2^{13}\right\rceil^4}$$

---

**Edit**: (I don't wan't to make other answer it's not that type of question) Or with [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

$$\binom{4+1}{3}^2 = 100$$

*How to get it?* Note that binomial coefficient equal to $10$ with small numbers are $\binom{5}{2}$ and $\binom{5}{3}$, but we have to have $2$ in power. So we just have to fin way to describe $\binom{5}{3}$ using $1,3,4$.

---

**Edit2**: I really didn't think about it! Just come to my mind. Here $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

$$ \varphi(312)+4 = 100$$

*How to get it?* Just note $1+2+3=6 = 3 \cdot 2$, so number made from this digits is divisible by 3. In very bad approximation $\varphi(n) \approx \frac{n}{3}$ and should be close to $100$, so we should check $312$. It could be too $214$ or $241$ (here very bad approximation for even $\varphi{(n)} = \frac{n}{2}$ and in fact $\varphi(214) = 106$). But it isn't.

---

**Edit3**: Ok, I was thinking a little bit now. It's last edit. Using [summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) and totient again.

$$ 12 +\sum_{k\mid34}\left(k + \varphi(k)\right) = 100 = 1 + 3 + \sum_{k \mid 42} k$$

Comment: There's also ${(\sigma(23)+1)} \times 4 = 100$ :-) (using the divisor function)

Comment: Nice, I was thinking about totient, but was too lazy to plug in numbers to see what would pop up.

Comment: Could also use $p_{24+1}+3$, where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number.

Comment: @GuriHarari Nice, you can improve your answer, using edit.

Comment: @HaoYe: I just thought isn't $\varphi(312) = 96 = 100-4$? I wasn't checking numbers. You can also improve your answer.

Answer (score 11):

What about $(1)(3!+4)^2$? Is factorial allowed? Is $2$ allowed as an exponent?

Comment: this gives 125...

Comment: I am a little weak on arithmetic.

Comment: I'm sure you aren't! (btw, 125 was the result of the original answer, this one gives in fact 100)

Answer (score 6):

How about $(4!+1)(3!-2)=100$

I can't see anyway of doing this without factorials.

Answer (score 4):

If factorial is allowed, then $(3!+4)^2$ could make the job (inspired by Nicholas).

Comment: I'm only in 7th grade don't know what that means

Comment: $3!$ means that you multiply $3\times 2\times 1$ (which is 6 then).

Comment: Ohh okay! That's a great example but now sure if that's allowed do u know a way without it?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately..

Comment: $(3! + 4)^2 = (3! + 4)(3! + 4) \subset$ repeated?

Comment: @Sarah I strongly believe, there is no way to do it with only `+,-,*,/`.

Comment: @MathApprentice Oh no! Going this way $2\cdot3 = 3+3$ is repeated.

Comment: Downvote. This doesn't have a 1.

Comment: @SuzuHirose I read, in the question, "**only** using the following digits 1234..."

Answer (score 3):

If roots are allowed then: $\sqrt{(3^2+1)^4}$

Comment: No roots can u find away only using numbers exponents and any math sign (ex.  23+1-4= 20)

Comment: i'm pretty sure that if you allow only +,-,x,/ and exponents than there's no solution.

Comment: @GuriHarari There is a solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$2\left[\left\lfloor\exp(4)\right\rfloor-(3+1)\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

(4+3+2+1)^2.

^2 is an exponent

Comment: Notice that this uses the digit $2$ twice.